# Закругление уголков у кастомного view

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Здравствуйте. Создал кастомный view. В нем рисуются прямоугольники rect. Необходимо левый нижний угол закруглить.
[image: custom view]
На рисунке обозначено красным цветом что нужно сделать. Каким образом можно сделать такое скругление?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой метод рисует прямоугольник с закругленным верхним и нижним правым углами, Вам нужно **убрать** закругление верхнего и будет работать так, как надо.

```
    /** Path в поле, чтобы не было инициализации в onDraw(). */
    private final Path eventPath = new Path();
    /** Радиус закругления. */
    private int eventRadius = 3;


    private void drawRoundRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom,
                               Paint paint, Canvas canvas) {
        eventPath.moveTo(left, top);
        eventPath.lineTo(right, top);
        eventPath.lineTo(right, bottom);
        eventPath.lineTo(left + eventRadius, bottom);
        eventPath.quadTo(left, bottom, left, bottom - eventRadius);
        eventPath.lineTo(left, top + eventRadius);
        eventPath.quadTo(left, top, left + eventRadius, top);
        canvas.drawPath(eventPath, paint);
        eventPath.reset();
    }
```

Comment: Мне что то кажется не пойдет ваш код.Давайте я вам скину свой view вы посмотрите.У меня просто все через rect

Comment: а какая разница, если рисуется на `Canvas`? Скиньте.

Comment: У вас последний имено прямоугольник скругляет?

Comment: причем тут прямоугольник?

Comment: Я делаю epg.То что на рисунке это прямоугольники drawrect

Comment: Вы сейчас рисуете методом `drawRect`?

Comment: вместо drawRect это метод

Comment: Нет то же не то буду пробовать

Comment: Код-то скинете?

Comment: на гитхаб дайте ссылку а то найти не могу куда кинуть код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53742/discussion-between-georgehardcore-and-ivan).

Answer (score 0):

В лейауте надо использовать `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    >
    <!-- blah-blah-->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Радиус угла закругления задается атрибутом  `app:cardCornerRadius`

Comment: Все равно не то.Если я в CardView размещу свой view то все равно мои тупые углы выходять за скругленные CardView

Comment: Покажите ваш `View`

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53742/discussion-between-georgehardcore-and-ivan

Comment: Если вы рисуете программно (а судя по чату так и есть), то естественно так работать не будет. Советую, не заниматься антипаттерном, а рисовать лейаут как положено в XML - тогда все будет ок. `CardView` сам будет выполнять роль прямоугольника